# Building a (simple) twitter-clone with CouchDB

Tags: join, twitter, couchdb, clone, timeline

I'm trying to build a (simple) twitter-clone which uses CouchDB as Database-Backend. 
Because of its reduced feature set, I'm almost finished with coding, but there's one thing left I can't solve with CouchDB - the per user timeline.

As with twitter, the per user timeline should show the tweets of all people I'm following, in a  chronological order. With SQL it's a quite simple Select-Statement, but I don't know how to reproduce this with CouchDBs Map/Reduce.

Here's the SQL-Statement I would use with an RDBMS:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE user_id IN [1,5,20,33,...] ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

**CouchDB schema details**

user-schema:

```
{
  _id:xxxxxxx,
  _rev:yyyyyy,
  "type":"user",
  "user_id":1,
  "username":"john",
  ...
}
```

tweet-schema:

```
{
"_id":"xxxx",
"_rev":"yyyy",
"type":"tweet",
"text":"Sample Text",
"user_id":1,
...
"created_at":"2011-10-17 10:21:36 +000"
}
```

With [view collations](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation) it's quite simple to query CouchDB for a list of "all tweets with user_id = 1 ordered chronologically".

But how do I retrieve a list of "all tweets which belongs to the users with the ID 1,2,3,... ordered chronologically"? Do I need another schema for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of doing this would be to **save the `created_at` as a timestamp** and then create a view, and map all tweets to the `user_id`:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.type == 'tweet'){
    emit(doc.user_id, doc);
  }
}
```

Then query the view with the user id's as keys, and in your application sort them however you want(most have a sort method for arrays).

**Edited one last time** - Was trying to make it all in couchDB... see revisions :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's bad practice. You are not reducing to small and simple values in your reduce function – that's not how reduce functions should be used.

Comment: Here, removed the reduce function and changed the map function.
@PartlyCloudy I shouldn't have used a reduce like that, happy now?

Comment: The 9999999999 is an arbitrary large enough number that is bigger than all of the timestamps.

Comment: This returns all tweets with the user_id starting from 1 to 9999999999, but what if I want to retrieve tweets for user_id = [1,2,6,33,87]?

Comment: You are right again, I fixed it up again... third time a charm?

Comment: It works, but only with a small amount of "tweets". With 1000 or more "tweets" I just get an array like [[null, null],[null, null], ...]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4342/discussion-between-shedokan-and-metty)

Answer (score 0):

Is that a CouchDB-only app? Or do you use something in between for additional buisness logic. In the latter case, you could achieve this by running multiple queries.

This might include merging different views. Another approach would be to add a list of "private readers" for each tweet. It allows user-specific (partial) views, but also introduces the complexity of adding the list of readers for each new tweet, or even updating the list in case of new followers or unfollow operations.

It's important to think of possible operations and their frequencies. So when you're mostly generating lists of tweets, it's better to shift the complexity into the way how to integrate the reader information into your documents (i.e. integrating the readers into your tweet doc) and then easily build efficient view indices.

If you have many changes to your data, it's better to design your database not to update too many existing documents at the same time. Instead, try to add data by adding new documents and aggregate via complex views.

But you have shown an edge case where the simple (1-dimensional) list-based index is not enough. You'd actually need secondary indices to filter by time and user-ids (given that fact that you also need partial ranges for both). But this not possible in CouchDB, so you need to work around by shifting "query" data into your docs and use them when building the view.